# Percentage memory indirect accesses

Tags: x86-64, cpu-architecture, intel-pin

I want to find what percentage of the memory load accesses in a program is memory indirect, for example, A[B[i]], A[(B[i]&mask)+c], A[B[C[i]]], etc.

My idea (have not started implementation) is to track if any register holds a value that has been loaded from memory. For ALU or bit operations, if one of the source registers is being tracked, then the destination will also be tracked. If such a register value is used to perform a memory access, then flag it as a memory indirect access.

Is there a better way to do it?
How can I go about implementing it?

Comment: Are you doing this dynamically, as in during runtime simulation/execution, or by static analysis?

Comment: Your method would catch *very* indirect accesses, like `reg = mean(array)` / `histogram[reg]++` where the index depended on many different values from memory.  So it kind of depends what you want to learn about programs and what you're hoping to do with the results.  Direct access to local vars would correctly be not counted, and global vars in executables.  But access to global vars in libraries would get counted because they go through the GOT (Global Offset Table) on Unix-like OSes: address loaded from GOT, then dereferenced.

Comment: @ErikEidt dynamically

Comment: @PeterCordes I am doing this for zstd. I saw that a lot of the accesses are some kind of indirect memory access. So, I wanted to know what percent of the accesses are indirect.

Comment: @PeterCordes I do want to catch those complex memory indirect accesses. I just realised that even `Obj->arr[i]` will be flagged as a memory indirect. I will also have to not track a register if it loaded value from `(rsp+displacement)`.

Comment: @ErikEidt: [intel-pin] is an infrastructure for dynamic instrumentation.

Comment: Oh, yeah you'd want to ignore RSP; it could get flagged as load-dependent after `pop rbp` / `mov rsp, rbp` or after an `alloca` or VLA.  And RBP in functions using it as a frame pointer, but most won't in an optimized build.  And yeah, looping over an array passed by function pointer could easily count them all as memory indirect, even though the access pattern is contiguous and address-calculations aren't adding significant latency.  Perhaps add a cool-off period of 1000 instructions, after which you don't count a register as still being a load-result, since even an L3 miss would be done.

Comment: I was thinking, `tracker(destination register) = tracker(source1) or tracker(source2) ...`. In case of a reg-reg move, the destination will be tracked if and only if the source is tracked. I think the loop over `obj->arr[I]` would probably be over by the time 1000 instructions are done. So, the next time the same instructions are executed, the pointer indirection will just set the tracking for the register again and the entire loop worth of accesses will be counted as memory indirect.